# Is it safe to use window.location.href and user input on JavaScript without validation?

Tags: javascript, xss

Is it safe to assign something to window.location.href and use that for navigating to different URLs? If not, how it should be secured?

For example:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<input id="search-btn" type="button" />
```

JS:

```
$('#search-btn').click(function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "/Search/" + $("#search").val();
});
```

Comment: just sanitize the user input.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely acceptable - the query will not be shown on any other computers. Once you send it to the server, it will search for whatever they stick into the textbox, and return a list of related documents. Because at no point is the query parsed as HTML, so you will be safe.